# Write contents into UTL_FILE immediately after a single iteration

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I have PL/SQL Block, it query from a Table function and I use a cursor to process it record by record, have some business logic and finally write the Qualified records into the file.

Number of records to be processed is upto 1 Million. And the total processing speed is roughly 10000 records per minute.(After testing with few chunks of data)

Now, that I need to indicate the processing status in a different environment, JSP.

```
DECLARE
 vSFile   utl_file.file_type;
 vNewLine VARCHAR2(200);
 my_cursor IS SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
 my_details my_cursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
  vSFile := utl_file.fopen('ORALOAD', file_name,'r');

  IF utl_file.is_open(vSFile) THEN
        utl_file.get_line(vSFile, vNewLine);


        OPEN my_cursor;
        LOOP
               FETCH my_cursor INTO my_details;
               EXIT WHEN sll_cur%NOTFOUND;
               -- Do processing
               utl_file.putf(logfile,'%s ',my_details);
               -- A info tht record completed!
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE logfile;
        CLOSE my_cursor;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --Error handling
END;
/
```

The log information written here, is not available until the completion of the process. So, I am unable to track, how far it is completed. 
Can someone please assist me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write data to the file you should use the FFLUSH procedure. For instance:

```
OPEN my_cursor;
   LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor INTO my_details;
      EXIT WHEN sll_cur%NOTFOUND;
      -- Do processing
      utl_file.putf(logfile,'%s ',my_details);
      -- Call the FFLUSH proc here..And contents are available immediately.
      utl_file.FFLUSH(logfile); 
END LOOP;
```

From the documentation:

> `FFLUSH` physically writes pending data to the file identified by the
>   file handle. Normally, data being written to a file is buffered. The
>   `FFLUSH` procedure forces the buffered data to be written to the file.
>   The data must be terminated with a newline character.
>
> Flushing is useful when the file must be read while still open. For
>   example, debugging messages can be flushed to the file so that they
>   can be read immediately.

There is more information on `UTL_FILE` in the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm).