# Mass Export of BLOB data to CSV

Tags: oracle, csv, export

I am working with an older Oracle database, I don't know which version of oracle, sorry, and I need to do a mass export of 200,000+ files worth of HTML data stored in BLOBs. I have downloaded and used both Toad and SQLDeveloper (Oracle's own DB GUI tool) and at best I am able to properly extract the HTML for a single row at a time.

Is there a way (query, tool, other GUI, etc...) that I can reliably do a mass export of all the BLOB data on this table to a CSV format?

Thank You.

Comment: The Oracle DB is 11g and mapping it to a CSV file is secondary to actually just getting the data in a non SQL format, can I export the BLOB data as actual HTML files instead?

Comment: `select [column_name] from [table]`?

Comment: That returns {binary}...which is the problem...I need to unencoded HTML files that are represented in each BLOB

Comment: You client is displaying it as 'binary' as a placeholder.... why do you have text stored in a BLOB rather than a CLOB?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_writing_blob_clob_os_file.htm

Comment: I didn't make it, I'm actually doing away with this DB altogether, moving it to Postgresql for a Rails app, I just need the metadata from the BLOBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this tool](http://www.withdata.com/oralobeditor/).

It works incredibly well for extracting content of any type out of any sort of LOB to a file type (HTML in this case). Takes about an hour to do 200,000 records though

Answer (score 0):

You can use utl_file built-in package through this you can write blob data to a file.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455752/write-contents-into-utl-file-immediately-after-a-single-iteration).